# XSLT Filter comparing two values in same sub node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to use XSLT (version 1 unfortunately..) am trying to filter out certain nodes via a comparison of two properties in the sub node.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <QueriesResponse xmlns="http://schemas.Movies.com/Movies">
      <Films xmlns="http://schemas.Movies.com/Movies">
        <Film>
          <FilmPostings>
            <FilmPosting>
              <FilmPostingDates>
                <FilmPostDate>2017-01-04T19:44:25.9530000-05:00</FilmPostDate>
                <FilmActiveDate>2017-01-04T19:44:25.9530000-05:00</FilmActiveDate>
              </FilmPostingDates>
            </FilmPosting>
          </FilmPostings>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <FilmPostings>
            <FilmPosting>
              <FilmPostingDates>
                <FilmPostDate>2017-01-04T19:50:06.3830000-05:00</FilmPostDate>
                <FilmActiveDate>2017-01-04T19:50:06.3100000-05:00</FilmActiveDate>
              </FilmPostingDates>
            </FilmPosting>
          </FilmPostings>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <FilmPostings>
            <FilmPosting>
              <FilmPostingDates>
                <FilmPostDate>2016-12-05T18:03:14.9830000-05:00</FilmPostDate>
                <FilmActiveDate>2017-01-02T00:16:52.7570000-05:00</FilmActiveDate>
              </FilmPostingDates>
            </FilmPosting>
          </FilmPostings>
        </Film>
      </Films>
    </QueriesResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here is my transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://schemas.Movies.com/Movies"
                xmlns:m="http://schemas.Movies.com/Movies"
                exclude-result-prefixes="m"
                >
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- standard identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This is mean to compare PostDate and ActiveDate, matching if different. It doesn't match any nodes in XML (but should match the final one). -->
  <xsl:template match="m:Film[m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates/m:FilmPostDate[1] [.!= m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates/m:FilmActiveDate[1]]]">
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This code does match the hard coded value (the second node).  -->  
  <!--<xsl:template match="m:Film[m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates/m:FilmPostDate[1] [.!= '2017-01-04T19:50:06.3830000-05:00']]">    
  </xsl:template>-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, you'll see in the commented-out bit that I can do a match with hard-coded values, so I'm obviously in the right area - I know that the code will exclude a whole Film node if it finds the match. But it's comparing the two node values that doesn't work.

I've tried all kinds of variations on the right side of the comparison, but it doesn't seem able to pick up the value of the ActiveDate.

Comment: Can you confirm what your logic actually is? Are you trying to remove `Film` elements where the `FilmPostDate` and `FilmActiveDate` are equal? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I am. The hard-coded example does something different, but it just confirmed to me that this would at least exclude A film node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `Film` elements where `FilmPostDate` and `FilmActiveDate` you can actually nest the conditions in the match attribute

```
<xsl:template 
     match="m:Film[m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates[m:FilmPostDate = m:FilmActiveDate]]" />
```

This assumes only one set of `FilmPostDate` and `FilmActiveDate` elements per `Film`. If there were more than one set, you can try remove `Film` elements where all occurrences are the same (or rather, then are no occurrences that were different).

```
<xsl:template 
     match="m:Film[not(m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates[m:FilmPostDate != m:FilmActiveDate])]" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I did not explain enough about the strange requirements around this stripped-down data model. I know there will always be exactly one FilmPosting per Film element and I don't care about handling different situations.

Comment: The actual template that does what I need to is:
<xsl:template match="m:Film[m:FilmPostings/m:FilmPosting/m:FilmPostingDates[m:FilmPostDate != m:FilmActiveDate]]">
  </xsl:template>
i.e. Where the values are different.

Comment: I now face the new challenge where - in the second node, the dates differ by milliseconds. Can I do some kind of parsing to remove this component from the date?

Comment: You could make use of some string handling here. Maybe just `substring` or a `substring-before` to do this. For example `substring-before(m:FilmPostDate, '.') = substring-before(m:FilmActiveDate, '.')`

Comment: That's perfect! For some reason I thought you could not use these functions in a "match" (as opposed to a "select"). This is brilliant. I think I have all I need now. Thank you so much for your help, Tim C!